# Why does the message icon show only for one number

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, messages, numbers

In one of my contacts I have added two phone numbers. I want to know why the message icon that let's me text to this number show up only for one of the two numbers as well as how can I fix this. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the phone number label **Work** to **mobile** or **iPhone**.

Apple makes the assumption here that only mobile phones can get text messages which is sometimes wrong.

Comment: That worked. However, isn't it wrong that only the labels iPhone and work let me message?

Comment: by work you probably meant mobile. Since non-mobile phones can also sometimes read/send text messages, yes it's kinda wrong ;)